# Positioning Divs with Javascript on DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
function contextMenu() {

    var menu = document.createElement("div");
    menu.innerHTML = "MY MENU";
    menu.style.position = 'absolute';
    menu.style.left = tempX;
    menu.style.top = tempY;
    document.body.appendChild(menu);

}


// Generic script to get cursor coordinates
var IE = document.all?true:false

if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)

document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

var tempX = 0
var tempY = 0

function getMouseXY(e) {
    if (IE) {
        tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
    } else {
        tempX = e.pageX
        tempY = e.pageY
    }

    if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
    if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}

    document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX
    document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY
    return true
}
```

the purpose of which is to create a div element at the cursor's position. It does create a div element and set `innerHTML` and `position: absolute`, but it does not set the `left` and `top` properties.

I created an alert box to check the values of `tempX` and `tempY`, and these are integers.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style values for `left` and `top` require units along with values, not just numeric values, or browser will ignore setting them

Try:

```
menu.style.left = tempX + 'px';
menu.style.top = tempY + 'px';
```